# Can one hear the shape of a DeRham ring ? Is any ring a DeRham ring?

Tags: differential-geometry, ring-theory

Sorry for the Clicbait title, but take $A$ a graded $\mathbb R$ commutative (in the graded sense) algebra of finite dimension.

Does there exist a smooth manifold $M$ having $A$ as a DeRham cohomology ring : $H^*(M) \simeq A$ ?

In the negative case, what would be a natural restriction that I missed on the structure of the DeRham ring ?

I was thinking of taking generators for the algebra and taking product of spheres. But i have problems when those generators verfies relations among them.

Comment: I've thought about this for a little while to no avail (other than some obvious conditions like what $A_0$ must be and that $A$ must arise as $A' \otimes_{\Bbb Z} A$ for some finitely generated $\Bbb Z$-algebra $A'$). It's worth noting that it is sufficient to provide such cohomology rings for finite CW complexes, as every finite CW complex is homotopy equivalent to a small open neighborhood of itself in some large Euclidean space.

Comment: So it seems that you are saying that this is equivalent to the same question replacing manifold by CW complexes and deRham by $\mathbb Z$ cohomology. Didn't noticed your condition on the integrability of the algebra. On the other hand I don't really understand your comment on $A_0$, could you please expand a bit ?

On this subject an [MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/178354/constructing-a-space-with-prescribed-cohomology-ring) redirects on an [article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0704.4002.pdf) Andersen and Grodal resolving this problem

Comment: .... resolving it by the negative

Comment: 0) Real cohomology, not $\Bbb Z$ cohomology. What I was saying above is that our algebra is induced up from some $\Bbb Z$-algebra, but we do not try to realize the $\Bbb Z$-algebra. This was mentioned so we don't use dumb relations like $x^3 = \pi y^2 + z$. 1) You always have a canonical isomorphism of algebras $H^0(X) \cong \Bbb R^{\# \text{components of } X}$. This is a product of copies of $\Bbb R$. The algebra $\Bbb C$ is not. 2) That paper does *not* answer your question in the negative, because it is not about real cohomology rings. (I am aware of the restrictions given by that paper.)

Comment: In fact that paper seems to give the answer in the positive for rings concentrated in even degrees.

Comment: I thought one corollary of their theorem was that we cannot have a space with cohomology with $\mathbb Z$ coefficient $\mathbb Z[x]$ with $deg(x) = 8$.
You're right as we would be interested in such a statement for some $\mathbb Z[x]/x^N$

Comment: That's irrelevant to your question. You can have spaces with lots of torsion in their integer homology, but real cohomology algebra $\Bbb R[x_8]$. An example is $K(\Bbb Z, 8)$.

Comment: oh I see thank you